# Rota no Angular 5 montada dinamicamente

Tags: angular, angular-routes, router, angular2-http

Tenho uma montagem de menu dinâmica no angular. A montagem é feita da seguinte forma:

```
  <ul class="pcoded-item pcoded-left-item" item-border="none" item-border-style="solid" subitem-border="solid" *ngFor="let asideItem of asideItems.views"
              appAccordionLink group="{{asideItem.module}}">
            <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" appAccordionLink group="{{asideItem.state}}">
              <a [routerLink]="['/', asideItem.route]" target="{{asideItem.target ? '_blank' : '_self'}}" appAccordionToggle>
                <span class="pcoded-micon">
                  <i class="{{ asideItem.icon}}"></i>
                </span>
                <span class="pcoded-mtext">{{ asideItem.name}}</span>
                <span *ngFor="let asideBadge of asideItem.badge" class="pcoded-badge label label-{{ asideBadge.type }}">{{asideBadge.value}}</span>
                <span class="pcoded-mcaret"></span>
              </a>
            </li>
```

A montagem está sendo feita da maneira correta, entretanto minha rota não está funcionando. Inspecionando os elementos, que possuem mais de um caminho (exemplo:  `cliente/novo`) o "/" está sendo substituido por %2F formando a rota como  `cliente%2Fnovo`.

Alguém tem uma ideia de como fazer com que o angular trabalhe com os caracteres desta forma?

Comment: Você precisa colocar um exemplo minimo ...

Answer (score 1):

Já tive esse problema em um projeto e resolvemos usando um `!` antes da barra nas rotas, por exemplo:

`<a href="#!/cliente/novo">`

O `!` diz ao `Angular` que é uma rota do lado cliente, um link para uma rota externa ou que tenha de ir no servidor não vai funcionar.

Comment: Ricardo, tens como postar um pedacinho do código de como ficou ? o routerLink? :s

Comment: Vou tentar achar onde foi, mas me lembro de ser algo assim: `<a [routerLink]="['/#/', menu.router, '/novo']">`